# hhvm not working with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hhvm

I have a wordpress website working without problems with Nginx, PHP5-FPM, Ubuntu configuration. I just installed HHVM and it is giving the following error:
**Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF, expecting $end in /active_themes_folder/functions.php on line 1**

When I checked it, first line contains only `"<?php ".` 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Only <php on the first line. I even moved stuff down so that there were 3 blank lines and it still said error on line 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new php file and copy pasted the contents of functions.php file. Thus, replacing old functions.php file with newly created functions.php file worked for me